# BeautifulSoup and prettify() function

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

To parse html codes of a website, I decided to use `BeautifulSoup` class and `prettify()` method. I wrote the code below.

```
import requests
import bs4

response = requests.get("https://www.doviz.com")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I execute this code on Mac terminal, indentation of the codes are not set. On the other hand, If I execute this code on windows cmd or PyCharm, all codes are set.

Do you know the reason for this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get("https://www.doviz.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Or, in words: construct the soup using `response.text`, not `response.content`.